# Cordova Plugin for Windows 10 written in C# instead of JS?

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, cordova, plugins

I'm still getting my feet wet with Cordova so please keep that in mind.

We have a Cordova project setup.  We have multiple plugins that are being used...both those that we've ready and ones in the public domain.

I need to write a plugin which will interface with a piece of hardware (type of hardware is not relevant).

To interface with the hardware, the hardware manufacturer has provided us with a .dll wrapper that exposes some simple API calls to make our lives easier.

We must use this .dll.  We have already written substantial C# .Net code for another Windows application and I would like to leverage that here.

The target device (a tablet) runs Windows 10.

In my research it seems that I must write the plugin in .js for WIndows 10.  Is that accurate?  Is it possible to write the plugin in C# .Net?

Basic workflow of the plugin:

JavaScript -> Cordova JS Interface -> .Net plugin code ->  .Net plugin code calls the .dll referenced above.

In short...is it possible to write the plugin code in C# .Net as opposed to JS and if so...are there any things I need to keep in mind when attempting to do the above workflow?

Thanks for your time.  Unfortunately no code to add as I've no written much yet other than proof of concept stuff.

Comment: I don't suppose that piece of hardware works over bluetooth or NFC?

Comment: Hi George.  No it doesn't.  It actually works via a USB dongle that acts as a middleman between the tablet and the device hardware.  They comm via RF.  It's old tech but unfortunately needs to be supported.

Comment: I'm foggy on Windows 10, but I assume it's possible given how could Cordova works with other OSes. You want to conduct a Google search for "create Cordova plugin Windows" that will contain the tutorials you need.

Comment: @George Stocker Not a duplicate.  That question you show references Win8.  This question references Windows 10 specifically.  Windows 10 guidance is to write the implementation in JS for the plugin.  I want to know if it's possible to still write this in .Net for Win 10.  That question references Win 8.  This question is valid and not a duplicate.  I'm looking for an answer if anyone can provide one.